# Entity Framework: attached objects with children

Tags: c#, entity-framework

As explained in this [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5557829/update-row-if-it-exists-else-insert-logic-with-entity-framework) if you like to insert or update an entity you can use the following approach:

```
if (myEntity.Id != 0)
{
    context.MyEntities.Attach(myEntity);
    context.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(myEntity, EntityState.Modified);
}
else
{
    context.MyEntities.AddObject(myEntity);
}

context.SaveChanges();
```

The problem is that in my case myEntity has some child related objects and therefore when I try to update it (myEntity.Id != 0) I receive the following exception:

```
System.InvalidOperationException was unhandled
Message=An object with a temporary EntityKey value cannot be attached to an object context.
```

If I remove the child objects (comment out) from myEntity everything works..

Does anybody know how to solve the problem? How can I update myEntity and save it with its child objects? THANKS!

### EDIT:

Here the solution to the problem: [stackoverflow.com/a/7969372/282649](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7969372/282649)

Comment: How is myEntity created? Where does that Id come from? And are the child objects new, or existing?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Storing a complex detached object graph in EF6](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21677558/storing-a-complex-detached-object-graph-in-ef6)

Comment: Hi, myEntity is already existing in the DB and loaded with EF. The Id is autoincrement and the child objects are already existing. Basically, what I want to do is simply to load my entity, change one of its property and store it back... Thanks for your feedback.

Comment: Rule #1 is: make sure everything existing is attached to the context before calling `Add` of the root entity. Further: set primitive foreign key values where possible (see *foreign key associations* vs. *independent associations*).

Comment: @Gert Arnold: is it possible to solve it without external library?

Comment: See my previous comment, that should do it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Entity 4.1 Updating an existing parent entity with new child Entities](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7968598/entity-4-1-updating-an-existing-parent-entity-with-new-child-entities)